# Правильное написание кода (PEP 8)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8

Нужен совет как быстро переучиться на правильное написание кода Python по правилам PEP 8.
Я привык писать код вот так:

```
from random import *
for i in range (10) :
    print (randint (100000,999999))
input ()
```

Надо переучиться на вот такое:

```
import random
for i in range(10):
    print(random.randint(100000, 999999))
input()
```

Я знаю, что этот вопрос не для Stack Overflow, но все равно, пожалуйста, напишите, как быстро переучиться на правильный стиль.

*Я работаю на смартфоне в Pydroid 3, компьютера у меня нет.*

Comment: Советую писать в Pycharm, там есть отличный анализатор кода, который каждый раз будет показывать те или иные ошибки. Попробуйте пытаться писать код так, чтобы предупреждения стремились к нулю, спустя пару недель такой практики вы легко переучитесь. Главное смотрите, что за ошибки вы совершаете, чтобы стараться не повторять их вновь.

Comment: @Bol4onok дело вкуса, же. У меня аллергия на PyCharm, глаза и голова болят от него=). Я лучше в vim писать буду

Comment: С каких пор там пробел перед скобкой у вызова функции?

Comment: @Dmitry Я просто указал на то что там отличный анализатор кода, который хорошо помогает. Если на vim есть такие же плагины, которые будут оказывать такую же помощь по pep8, то почему бы и нет.

Comment: @Dmitry К сожалению, на данный момент использую Windows, поэтому ощутить романтику в полной мере не могу, но как начну использовать GNU/Linux, обязательно воспользуюсь всеми красотами Neovim'a

Comment: @Dmitry, IMHO. Учиться (переучиваться) лучше на PyCharm. Он реально выправляет людям стиль написания кода. Отучает сваливать код в кучу и вообще лепить всякую несуразицу. Что касается vim - это да. Это классика и YouCompleteMe решает проблему автодополнения кода, но (опять же IMHO) годен для того, чтобы побырому из косоли на серваке поправить косяк. Для меня не юзабелен еще по той причине, что я обычно пишу код под работу с бд, а тут с JentBrain не думаю чтобы кто-то мог соперничать, даже VS Code не Ice )

Comment: Последнее обновление все меняет. Читайте документацию к PEP8. Соблюдайте ее. И для меня странно, что у кого то в мире нет компьютера. Откуда вы и сколько вам?

Comment: Ну вообще-то вариант `from random import randint` тоже нормальный, если вам не нужен из модуля миллион методов. И нужно ставить пустую строку после импортов.

Comment: @Dmitry Мне 12 лет

Comment: @Пушистик круто) я бы на месте ваших родителей уже крепко бы задумался о покупке ПК. Андроид любит пробелы автоматически ставить. Учите английский, читайте pep8 на досуге

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень хороший вопрос. Мне лично сложно читать кое-как написанный код.

Правильные шаги ниже. Если совсем нет времени или сильно неохота, то делайте только третий шаг. Усилий уйдёт меньше в этом случае, но научитесь не так быстро.

1. Выучите PEP-8 наизусть или близко к этому. Читайте на английском, наши переводы урезаны.
2. Найдите упражнения на PEP-8 в инете и все их делайте по памяти, не глядя в PEP-8 (часть была на Stepik). Повторяйте пока без ошибок не будет получаться.
3. Пишите далее в PyCharm, он вам будет указывать на ошибки. Обдумывайте каждую их перед исправлением.

Answer (score 1):

Устанавливайте [autopep8](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/) и пользуйтесь. Задавайтесь вопросами: "Почему так написано/форматировано?". И, думаю, со временем все придет.

Тут VScode в последнем обновлении анонсировала решение со стилем в python для [`black`](https://github.com/psf/black). Наглядно посмотреть можно [здесь](https://black.vercel.app/)

Выпущено расширение для `black style` кода. [Вот оно](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.black-formatter). Только это пока `pre-release`.